# Opening files with dafault applications using subprocess module python (Confusion)

Tags: python

```
import subprocess

subprocess.Popen(["start", r"C:\Users\John\Desktop\Goals.txt"], shell=True)
```

I expect windows (my operating system) would launch, Notepad.exe to handle the Goals.txt file.

Instead it returned this:

[image]

What is a `venv`  and why is there a `venv` ? How can I fix this? I also tried using other files such as `"C:\Windows\Media\Alarm01.wav"` and this works. Is it because where the file is stored at? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

## venv

The `venv` notation indicates that the current shell is using a "virtual env". When such an env is activated, the most important difference is that the `PATH` value has changed. The `PATH` environment variable is used to search through different directories for a typed executable. For example, if you type `python` in your terminal, it'll execute the first `python` executable it finds from the list of directories mentioned in the environment variable `PATH`.

This is completely **normal and good practice**.

When you work on different projects, you sometimes want to mix and match different Python versions and package versions. For this reason, it is strongly recommended to always simply create a new `venv` for each new project. That way, you minimize regression issues. You won't break something in a previous project just because a new project needed to upgrade a version (Python/package/both).

These `venv` can be managed manually with `python -m venv`. Or, alternatively, by your IDE. When a new `venv` is created, it includes both a separate Python and installed packages. When you activate the `venv` (by executing bin/activate), it also adds an indicator to your shell - The `(venv)` you see in your terminal.

## Popen

I can't link an exact paragraph that helps but from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor)

```
If shell is True, the specified command will be executed through the shell.
...
...
On Windows with shell=True, the COMSPEC environment variable specifies the default shell. 
The only time you need to specify shell=True on Windows is when the command you wish to 
execute is built into the shell (e.g. dir or copy). You do not need shell=True to run a 
batch file or console-based executable.
```

it *seems* like `shell=True` is the issue.